# TFS : Creating a new trunk from a branch

Tags: tfs

I am having some legacy issues where development was done in the branch in the past. I would like to create a trunk from that branch. Is it even possible to do that in TFS?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't merge the changes from the branch into the old trunk?

Comment: 3 years of changes and too many upgrades of 3rd party of controls. I was thinking of just creating a trunk from this branch would be an easier option

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit heavy handed, but I just did a quick test and it works as you would expect. Delete the original trunk, then create a new branch from the active branch and name it "trunk".

You do need to check-in the deletion of the original trunk before attempting to create the new trunk branch

Alternatively, you could rename the active branch "trunk" after deleting the original, and then create a new branch from there to match your preferred structure.

Another alternative, if you truly want to **permanently** remove the original trunk *and* all of its history is to use [`tf destroy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to remove it. Then create a new trunk from the current branch. Thanks @JamesReed for the reminder about the `destroy` command.

Comment: be careful with this, when you delete the "trunk" folder, it isn't really gone. When you branch a new "trunk" then the old folder will be undeleted and the files overwritten. This might be what you want. If you really want to get rid of the old "trunk" you should use the "destroy" command. However this will remove the folder completely from TFS and it will be as if it never existed

Comment: Personally, I prefer to keep the history just in case I ever needed to go back. Good tip about "destroy" though, I only ever use it if I don't have any alternative.